# How to create a listner for Materialize toast tooltips created dynamically?

Tags: jquery, listener, materialize

I have following code to activate the Toast Tooltip component:

```
$(function(){   
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50}); 
});
```

however, it doesn't work when we have objects created dinamically.

Can I create some kind of listener using **JQuery.on**?

Comment: You could activate the tooltip when you create your dynamic elements. How are you creating them exactly?

Comment: Yes @PierreC. However, it's a kind of "workaround" and I would like to do this in the right way. The elements/buttons has been created by Datatable.net  using columnDefs renderization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [draw events](https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/) of datatables to reinitialize [the tooltips](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) on your table whenever something has changed.

```
$('#myTable').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    $('#myTable .tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50}); 
} );
```

You can also remove the `tooltipped` class to only initialize the tooltip events once:

```
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
    $('#myTable .tooltipped')
        .removeClass('tooltipped')
        .tooltip({delay: 50});
});
```

Comment: On this way, I would call many times the tooltip, creating many DOM elements for the tooltip